# Replicating Project using NuGet

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

NuGet noob here. I want to use NuGet to completely replicate a couple of projects within my solution for use in creating different flavors for different clients. Well, I don't want to, my boss does. I suggested project templates, but apparently, we are more interested in NuGet (which, does have its advantages for keeping these client-flavored builds up to date with our vanilla).

I started off by dropping a couple of .nuspec files into the two projects we're creating packages of (we'll call them our web.ui and servicehost) and adding in all their NuGet dependencies. We use TeamCity to build and push out our packages so setting these packages to be pushed out was a simple task - then I ran into the problem of a lack of contents in my NuGet package - so I added in a  parameter..., and well I'll post that cleansed nuspec here. The problem is, I'm not getting EVERYTHING in that project with my current setup. I want it so that when I install my NuGet package onto the blank project, it replicates what is in the vanilla. Thank you for your help, again, I'm entirely new to NuGet.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>####.ServiceHost</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>####.ServiceHost</title>
    <authors>##</authors>
    <owners>##</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>####.ServiceHost</description>
    <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2018, ########</copyright>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="net462">
      <dependency id="AntiXSS" version="4.2.1" />
      <dependency id="Aspose.Cells" version="8.7.0" />
      <dependency id="Aspose.Email" version="6.2.0" />
      <dependency id="Aspose.Pdf" version="11.3.0" />
      <dependency id="Aspose.Words" version="16.1.0" />
      <dependency id="EO.Pdf" version="15.3.1.0" />
      <dependency id="FileHelpers" version="2.0.0.0" />
      <dependency id="HtmlAgilityPack" version="1.4.6" />
      <dependency id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="1.0.0" />
      <dependency id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.8.2" />
      <dependency id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.8.2" />
      <dependency id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.8.2" />
      <dependency id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="3.2.3" />
      <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" />
      <dependency id="SSH.NET" version="2016.0.0" />
      <dependency id="System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync" version="4.0.11" />
      <dependency id="System.Dynamic.Runtime" version="4.0.0" />
      <dependency id="System.Linq.Queryable" version="4.0.0" />
      <dependency id="System.Net.Requests" version="4.0.11" />
      <dependency id="System.Spatial" version="5.8.2" />
      <dependency id="####" version="543.0.0" />
      <dependency id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="8.1.4" />
      <dependency id="####" version="42.0.0" />
      <dependency id="####" version="1.13.206" />
      <dependency id="####" version="1.13.206" />
        </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="**\*" target="lib" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Comment: If you want source files to be included you need to use the the [content target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files) not the lib target. `<file src="**\*.*" target="content" />` This works for packages.config projects but will not work with projects that use PackageReference. PackageReference has a different mechanism for files and also does not copy files into the project. Not sure if NuGet is a good fit here for distributing files. It is a better fit for distributing assemblies.

Comment: Well now it is taking all the files I need over, but I'm not getting the correct references I need to build my solution. Please advise?